# enable carrot_planner

Tags: ros, navigation, dwa, carrot-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi folks,

How can I enable the carrot_planner in the navigation stack without have to write any code?
Is there a parameter to enable it (in the same way we can enable/disable dwa)?

Thanks

edit1:

After I include that line inside move_base launcher to include carror, now I get this error:

```
[FATAL] [1424988770.617038890]: Failed to create the carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner planner, are you sure it is properly registered and that the containing library is built? Exception: According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner with base class type nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner does not exist. Declared types are  navfn/NavfnROS
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203801/enable-carrot_planner/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2015-02-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2015-02-27**:
what version of ROS are you using? do you have carrot_planner installed? eg.: roscd carrot_planner works?

**Comment by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on 2015-02-27**:
I just installed it. I did not have it before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can add this line to your launch file, after your move_base node

```
<node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner"/>
   .
   .
   .
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1